# How do I update the picker view in the original viewController after dismiss a popover in swift 3?

Tags: swift, segue, uipickerview, viewcontroller, popover

I am displaying a popover segue after a button is pressed with the purpose of adding a car brand to my picker view in the original `viewController` so the user can return and select the new brand just added in that picker view, the new car brand is added to the database sussesfuly but I cannot update the picker view, actually after the popover is dismiss, nothing happened, I already try to add a `reloadAllComponents in viewWillAppear, viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear` but nothing happened, some one can help me please?

Kindly look at the images below:

**Popover:**

[image]

**Button segue:**

[image]

my code:

OriginalViewController

```
    import UIKit
    import CoreData

    class VehicleAddViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    // MARK: - Model

    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext

    // MARK: - Properties
    private final var pickerBrandData: [String]?

    private final var pickerBrandResult: String? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.Brand.delegate = self
        self.Brand.dataSource = self
    }

    // MARK: - Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var Brand: UIPickerView

    //MARK: Data Sources

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        switch pickerView.tag {
            case 1:
                if pickerBrandData == nil {
                    return 0
                } else {
                    return pickerBrandData!.count
                }
            default:
                return 0
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        switch pickerView.tag {
        case 1:
            return pickerBrandData?[row]
        default:
            return nil
        }

    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        switch pickerView.tag {
        case 1:
            pickerBrandResult = pickerBrandData?[row]
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    // MARK: - Navigation

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        switch segue.identifier! {
            case "Quick Brand Add Segue":
                let DestViewController = segue.destination as? QuickBrandAddViewController
                let ReceiveViewController = DestViewController?.contentViewController
                    if let PopOverD = ReceiveViewController?.popoverPresentationController {
                        let minimunSize = ReceiveViewController?.view.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
                        ReceiveViewController?.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: (minimunSize?.width)!, height: (minimunSize?.height)!)
                        PopOverD.delegate = self
                    DestViewController?.newSetOfBrands = pickerBrandData
                }
                break
            default:
                break
            }
            // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
         }
     }

extension UIViewController {
    var contentViewController: UIViewController {
        if let navcon = self as? UINavigationController {
            return navcon.visibleViewController!
        } else {
            return self
        }
    }
}
```

popover viewController

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class QuickBrandAddViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    // MARK: - Model

    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext

    var newSetOfBrands: [String]?

    // MARK: - Properties

    private final var activeTextField: UITextField?

    // MARK: - Lifecycle methods

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.Brand.delegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Outlets

    @IBOutlet weak var Brand: UITextField!

    // MARK: - Delegate

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        activeTextField = textField
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if activeTextField != nil {
            updateDatabase(description: (activeTextField!.text)!)
        }
        managedObjectContext?.performAndWait {
            self.newSetOfBrands = Car_Brand.fetchBrand(inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!)!
        }
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.activeTextField?.resignFirstResponder()
            self.view.endEditing(true)
            }, completion: nil)
        presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        return false
    }

    // MARK: - Methods

    private func updateDatabase(description: String) {
        managedObjectContext?.perform {
            _ = Car_Brand.insertNew(brandDescription: description, inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!)
            do {
                try self.managedObjectContext?.save()
            } catch let error {
                print ("Core Data Error: \(error)")
            }
        }
        printDatabesesStatistics()
    }

    private func printDatabesesStatistics() {
        managedObjectContext?.perform() {
            do {
                let brandCount = try self.managedObjectContext!.count(for: NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Car_Brand"))
            print (brandCount)
            } catch let error {
                print ("Core Data Error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

CoreDataClass.swift

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


public class Car_Brand: NSManagedObject {

    class func insertNew (brandDescription: String, inManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Car_Brand? {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Car_Brand> = Car_Brand.fetchRequest()
        request.predicate = NSPredicate (format: "brand = %@", brandDescription)
        if let brand = (try? context.fetch(request))?.first {
            return brand
        } else if let brand = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Car_Brand", into: context) as? Car_Brand {
            brand.brand = brandDescription
            return brand
        }
        return nil
    }

    class func fetchBrand (inManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> [String]? {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Car_Brand> = Car_Brand.fetchRequest()
        request.propertiesToFetch = ["brand"]
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "brand", ascending: true)]
        if let preBrandList = try? context.fetch(request) as [Car_Brand] {
            var brandList: [String] = []
            for preBrandList in preBrandList {
                brandList.append(preBrandList.brand!)
            }
            return brandList
        } else {
            return nil
        }

    }

}
```

CoreDataProperties.swift

```
import Foundation
import CoreData 

extension Car_Brand {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Car_Brand> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Car_Brand>(entityName: "Car_Brand");
    }

    @NSManaged public var brand: String?
    @NSManaged public var id_brand: NSSet?
    @NSManaged public var id_model: NSSet?

}

// MARK: Generated accessors for id_brand
extension Car_Brand {

    @objc(addId_brandObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToId_brand(_ value: Vehicle)

    @objc(removeId_brandObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromId_brand(_ value: Vehicle)

    @objc(addId_brand:)
    @NSManaged public func addToId_brand(_ values: NSSet)

    @objc(removeId_brand:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromId_brand(_ values: NSSet)

}

// MARK: Generated accessors for id_model
extension Car_Brand {

    @objc(addId_modelObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToId_model(_ value: Model)

    @objc(removeId_modelObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromId_model(_ value: Model)

    @objc(addId_model:)
    @NSManaged public func addToId_model(_ values: NSSet)

    @objc(removeId_model:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromId_model(_ values: NSSet)

}
```

Comment: Just update the datasource array of `pickerView` when you add new brand.

Comment: I'm on my phone so bare with me. You need to create a delegate for the popped over viewcontroller. So before you show the popover you set the delegate of the popover as the presenting view controller. And before you dismiss the popover what you do is you save the new object. Be sure to call the finishPendingChanges(maybe) method on the managed object context just to make sure. If you have two managedObjectContexts be sure that you synchronize them. And then you call the delegate method which is implemented in the presenting view controller. The method will update the data and reload the picker

Comment: I already try to create a instance of the array in the popover viewController and update the value but is not working, and I dond't know where to update the value in the original viewController because it suppose to be syncronized with the model of the popover segue but is not working either  @vaibhav

Comment: You can show your code how you doing with segue and datasource so we can understand as well ..

Comment: I already add the code, thanks @vaibhav

Answer (score 0):

After several tests I found that the key is unwind segue, in that way is possible to perform an action after the user come back to the original segue, so I change the strategy of just dismiss for a unwind segue like this:

in the original viewController I add:

```
  // MARK: - Navigation
   @IBAction func updateBrandPicker(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    var rowPosition = 0;
    let previousPickerBrandData = pickerBrandData

    // Fetch the new list of Brands
    managedObjectContext?.perform {
        self.pickerBrandData = Car_Brand.fetchBrand(inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!)!
        self.Brand.reloadAllComponents()

        // Obtain new brand
        let newSetBrands: Set = Set(self.pickerBrandData!)
        var differencePickerBrandData: Set = Set(newSetBrands)
        differencePickerBrandData.subtract(previousPickerBrandData!)
        let theNewBrand = Array(differencePickerBrandData)

        // Select the new brand in the pickerView
        if theNewBrand.count > 0 {
            for brandName in self.pickerBrandData! {
                if brandName == theNewBrand[0] {
                    self.Brand.selectRow(rowPosition, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
                    break
                }
                rowPosition += 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in the popover viewController I add:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if Brand != nil {
        updateDatabase(description: (Brand!.text)!)
    }
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "updateBrandPicker", sender: Any?.self)
}

// MARK: - Actions

@IBAction func Save(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// MARK: - Delegate

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.Brand?.resignFirstResponder()
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        }, completion: nil)
    presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    return false
}
```

In the stroyboard just add the unwind segue by Ctrl + dragging to Exit button and edditing the identifiere field check the next images:

[image]

[image]

And the pickerView should update and select the new registry just added